# How to set required field by using the wp_dropdown_categories?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, validation

After tried a lot I did not find any solution that works for me. I am using the below code to display the categories as a dropdown list.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=category' ); ?>
```

The dropdown display perfectly as expected but how can I make it required field? I tried by using jQuery with the following code but it works with some browser and sometimes it does not.

```
jQuery("#cat").attr("required", true);
jQuery("#cat option:first").val(null);
```

So is there a way that I can make the dropdown field required? I read the codex but did not find any parameter that will make it required field and even I never found an topic in online regarding this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it the other way around, as `required` works only with dropdowns that have empty value, if you set it later, some browsers may not recognize it:

```
jQuery("#cat option:first").val(null);
jQuery("#cat").attr("required", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update: WordPress 4.6**

As from WordPress 4.6 we can add a 'required' attribute directly to wp_dropdown_categories().

```
<?php
$dropdown_args = array(
    'show_option_none'   => __( 'Select Company', 'text-domain' ),
    'taxonomy'           => 'company',
    'required'           => true
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_args );
```

Source: [Core Tract Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31909)